# How to display webform results under the webform with contextual filters?

Tags: 7

I created a view listing webform fields 
New View » Webform Submissions » Unformatted list of Rendered submissions

It gives me all the submitted data of all the webforms of the website.

I'm looking for a way to have under each webform its results.

So when i visit : `website.com/webform/id678`
under the form, i would like to have a block showing the previously submitted data i'll be using a pager to only display the 5 latest submissions and be able to browse through submissions if i want to.

This is possible with the contextual filter of Views but i can't seem to figure out how to configure it correctly

thanks

I'm using Drupal 7.56 and webform 4.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. create a `views block display` of your view

configure the view as you wish
but you have to add contextual filter by `content:nid` as shown below with setting: `raw value from URL, path compoment 2`

[image]

We have to specify validation criteria `content: webform` as shown below

[image]

### 2. add the views block in a block region

Now if you visit a webform will show under it the relevant submissions

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what i needed. Drupal is amazing and the community is even better. Thanks